# While fetching data from MemCache(Docker) getting a performance issue..stack trace below

Tags: docker, memcached

net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient:get:1016 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 74 ms)
                      net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient:get0:1058 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 74 ms)
                       net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient:fetch0:644 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 74 ms)
                        net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient:latchWait:2516 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 74 ms)
                         java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport:parkNanos:215 (method time = 74 ms, total time = 74 ms)